# select dropdown and each block - Ruby/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a simple `each` block that takes each category and creates an `option`

```
@categories = Category.all

<select id="bike_category_filter" multiple="multiple">
  <% @categories.each do |c| %>
    <option value="<%= c.name %>"><%= c.name %></option>
  <% end %>
```

What I would like to with the categories `Men and Women` (so c.name) is surround them with an `<optgroup>` tag. How could I achieve that, a link to a resource or explanation on where to look would suffice, not necessarily looking for someone to give me the answer

The desired output would look like

```
<select>
  <optgroup label="Gender">
    <option value="cat1">Men</option>
    <option value="cat2">Women</option>
  </optgroup>
    <option value="cat3">Cat5</option>
    <option value="cat4">Cat4</option>
</select>
```

Thanks

Comment: what is the criteria for identify the category is for `Men` or `Woman`?

Comment: do you mean how that value is gathered? if so `c.name`

Comment: your required this https://jsfiddle.net/6tqamxvz/ output right?

Comment: ive updated my question with desired output, thank you

Comment: Ok, So now my question is How you identufy that category is goes under `Gender optgroup` ?

Comment: well there are only 2, `Men, Women`, nothing else goes under the `Gender optgroup`

Comment: https://select2.github.io/examples.html look at this once

Comment: thanks @Mukesh I already use https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect which is why i want to wrap two of my categories in an optgroup.... what am i looking at in particular?

Comment: Dynamically I think it is not possible... By using static logic....It can be done.....with using html select and ruby each loop and if conditions

Answer (score 0):

In the end i implemented this solution, I still feel that this could be done more elegantly

```
Controller

@gender_categories = Category.where(name: ['Mens', 'Womens'])
@categories = Category.where.not(name: ['Mens', 'Womens'] )

View 

<select id="bike_category_filter" multiple="multiple">
  <optgroup label="Gender">
    <% @gender_categories.each do |c| %>
      <option value="<%= c.name %>"><%= c.name %></option>
    <% end %>
  </optgroup>

  <optgroup label=" Bike Type">
    <% @categories.each do |c| %>
      <option value="<%= c.name %>"><%= c.name %></option>
    <% end %>
 </optgroup>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a nifty method called `partition`, which groups items into two groups.

**controller:**

```
@primary_group, @secondary_group = Category.all.partition { |c| c.name == 'Men' or c.name == 'Woman'}
```

**view**

```
<select id="bike_category_filter" multiple="multiple">
  <optgroup label="Gender">
    <% @primary_group.each do |c| %>
      <option value="<%= c.name %>"><%= c.name %></option>
    <% end %>
  </optgroup>

  <% @secondary_group.each do |c| %>
    <option value="<%= c.name %>"><%= c.name %></option>
  <% end %>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I think any logic in the view is a no no. Appreciate you taking the time to answer though